# VLC stopped working correctly after upgrade to Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: vlc

I upgraded to Lubuntu 15.04 and lost video when using VLC 2.2.1. Audio still works. Any ideas?

Comment: HAve you tried to run it from a terminal ? Did it showed any error ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Does VLC still work using the guest session???

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to re install it ?

make sure you have everything updated with

sudo apt-get update
and
sudo apt-get upgrade

i got a similar error when i upgraded to ubuntu 15.04 but after i updated everything and restarted the pc, vlc worked fine, i hope it helps you too

Comment: I did try to reinstall w/o success.  I will verify all updates - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Verified upgrade, updates, drivers, and codecs. uninstalled and reinstalled VLC.  Same problem continues; VLC plays with auido, but no video.  If i can revert back to 14.10, then i'll do so, and then try the upgrade again.  Thanks!